# How to make sql to produce 2 conditions

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table name notis. The attribute are nomborFail(Primary Key varchar), tarikhNotis2(date), tarikhNotis3(date) and status(varchar).
I want to show data that have date in more tarikhNotis2 and tarikhNotis3
and also show data more than 2 if tarikhNotis3 are NULL.

It is possible I can do this?

```
SELECT * FROM notis  WHERE ((CURRENT_DATE() > tarikhNotis2 AND tarikhNotis3=NULL) OR (CURRENT_DATE() > tarikhNotis2 AND CURRENT_DATE() < tarikhNotis3)) AND status='BELUM SELESAI'
```